# Step by step guide to connect to Blogger using Drivel

Tags: drivel

I use Ubuntu 12.04. Does any body know a step-by-step guide to connect Drivel to Blogger?

I have tried several times to log in using my Google account, but it always returns an error.

```
<span weight="bold" size="larger">Server error</span>

Network connection failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Below should have been the normal answer, sadly Drivel has a bug there too. Please subscribe to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/drivel/+bug/1236068

In Drivel login, you should enter your username and password* then select ATOM/Blogger 2.0, as show in the image:

[image]

- If you use double authentication, read this page to create your Application password https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Comment: Does it even work in 16.04?

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov the bug isn't fixed, so I would say "no".